# Symfony, disable cache for specific route

Tags: symfony, caching, twig

I have a twig page that is playing songs, show song title, artist and image for the specific song playing live. The page is for a web-radio page.

The problem is sometimes when I get in that page, the image, song title, artist of the previous song. I can just fix it by pressing ctrl+f5. And the song sometimes has some feedback like the actual song is playing and cut playing the previous song at each seconds they changed. I want to disable the cache only for the route not the entire application or bundle.

Comment: How did you set a cache globally ? It can only for a route, no ?

Comment: I have no idea how to set or remove a cache for bundle or route. I use the console to delete cache or I just delete the cache folder. Or just set twig: cache to false. How do you set a cache?

Comment: The app cache can not affect pages that are rendered. Your twig templates are only cached in php format for faster execution. But there is no content cached by the default symfony config (http cache has to be enabled).

Comment: So you mean, creating the page in PHP will fix my problem because Symfony doesn't cache the PHP page files ? Or It doesn't have any solution other then creating the web page without Symfony?

Comment: I just realize the cache issue is not Symfony, but a browser cache issue.

Answer (score 1):

My problem wasn't have nothing to do with Symfony. It was just a cache browser trouble. I fixed it by generating new link to avoid the browser using cache.